# Add-ons not found anymore in GRASS 7.8 installation

Tags: installation, ubuntu, linux, extensions, add-ons

I use GRASS GIS 7.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Last time I used GRASS, I was able to use add-ons, such as r.stream.snap and r.accumulate. But now when I start GRASS, I get a series of errors in the terminal that say, for example,

```
r.stream.snap: Unable to fetch interface description for command '<r.stream.snap>'.

Details: <[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r.stream.snap': 'r.stream.snap'>
r.stream.stats: Unable to fetch interface description for command '<r.stream.stats>'.
```

At the end, it says

```
WARNING: Some addons failed when loading. Please consider to update your addons by running 'g.extension.all -f'.
```

I tried removing GRASS with Synaptic then reinstalling it the same way, but it did not fix the problem.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? I am a novice Linux user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related but installing addons with the default Grass version 7.8 supplied with Ubuntu has been broken for a long time due to [some repository restructuring](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/1678/files). Possibly also some more general changes at Github may have affected the situation recently.

I fixed my version by installing Node and degit (`sudo npm i -g degit`), and modifying the Python code in `/usr/lib/grass78/scripts/g.extension` to use degit instead of svn in downloads:

```
1336c1336,1337
<     if grass.call(['svn', 'export',
---
> 
>     if grass.call(['degit',
1338a1340
> 
1522a1525
> 
2181,2182c2184,2185
<         git_url = 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/trunk/' \
<                    'grass{version}/{module_class}/{module_name}' \
---
>         git_url = 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/src/' \
>                    '{module_class}/{module_name}#grass{version}' \
2184a2188
>
```